# Why is 'convergence in distribution' weaker than 'convergence in probability'?

Tags: probability, statistics

I met this problem when I was enrolled in an undergraduate course in statistics, my tutor explained that:

> Convergence in distribution is weak since we only need the convergence happens in the distribution function, not the random variable itself. While the basic idea behind the convergence in probability is that the probability of an “unusual” event, {|Xn − X| > ε}, becomes smaller and smaller as the sequence progresses.

I can't really understand this statement, even if I read some counterexamples that some sequences converge in distribution but not in probability.

Would you please give me an more mathematical and analytical explanation about the differences, instead of some counterexamples?

Comment: (For example think of recording the heads and the tails of coin throws as two Bernoulli variables. They will have he same distribution but are never equal.)

Comment: (Or take i.i.d. variables.)

Answer (score 1):

First, convergence in probability $\implies $ convergence in distribution. Therefore, in this point of view, it's weak. Moreover, to have $X_n\to X$ in probability, you need at least that the sequence $(X_n)$ and $X$ lives in the same probability space, whereas in the convergence in distribution, $(X_n)$ and $X$ can lives in different probability space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me give an example to show my confusion, we know that uniform continuity is stronger than normal continuity, this comparative relationship was intuitive for me. However, although I know that convergence in probability ⟹ convergence in distribution, but I can't 'feel' that weakness intuitively, I don't understand where does the weakness come from.

Answer (score 1):

- Convergence in distribution is about convergence of Borel probability measures defined on some topological space. The objects of interest are probability measures, not random variables. When $\Omega$ is a nice metric space ($\mathbb{R}^d$ for example), convergence in metric can be seen as convergence in a certain topology defined on the space of Probability measures $\mathscr{M}$ on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$. This topology is the smallest topology that makes the functions $\Lambda_f:\mathscr{M}(\Omega)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\mu\mapsto \int_\Omega f(s)\,\mu(ds)$, continuous (the functions $f$ is bounded and continuous on $\Omega$); hence the name ***weak convergence***. That is equivalent to saying that  $\mu_n\Longrightarrow\mu$ if for any $f\in\mathcal{C}_b(\Omega)$
  $$\int_\Omega f(s)\,\mu(ds)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_\Omega f(s)\mu(ds)$$
  If $X_n$ and $X$ are real valued random variables (not necessarily defined on a common probability space), then one after writes $X_n\Longrightarrow X$ to mean that the distribution $\mu_n$ of $X_n$ (which is a Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$) converges weakly to the distribution $\mu$ of $X$.
- Convergence in measure) or probability is about convergence of random variables. For real-valued random variables, convergence in measure can be set up in terms of convergence in a metric space:
  On the space of finite measurable functions $\mathcal{L}_0(\Omega)$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$,
  $$d(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[\min(1,|X-Y|)]$$
  defines a metric. Convergence in measure is equivalent to convergence in $(\mathcal{L}_0(\Omega),d)$.